# Maven Spring project not executing due to ClassNotFoundException

Tags: spring, maven, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm working on a Spring/Maven tutorial to test splitting up Spring bean definitions between multiple files.  My issue is that `mvn -X -e exec:java` shows build failure, but running as a Java application within STS shows the proper output.

My project is set up as `com.jason.basicOne`, with `com.jason` as the groupId and `basicOne` as the artifactId.  The only compiler warning within STS is due to an imported class not being used.

Things I've done:

- Used the `<import />` tags to reference the secondary files, and enabled the usage within Spring Properties.
- Refreshed the project several times via `mvn clean` and `mvn package`

But the `ClassNotFoundException` still shows up for `com.jason.App`.  What other things should I look for?

**EDIT**

I found the error.  In my pom.xml, I use the `exec-maven-plugin` to enable execution via `mvn exec:java` on the command line.  The plugin definition was set to a previous project, from which I cut and pasted to the new project.  The updated package name was not included, which is why the project executed via STS and not command line.

Answer (score 0):

Your example compiles correctly if you
1. check com.jason.App class. Should it read com.jason.basicOne.App instead?
2. see if your pom.xml has right spring jars.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
<version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version> 
</dependency>
```

Make sure your ".m2/" does not have an old spring which is referenced by your pom.xml

Comment: I have the spring context dependency within the pom.xml and only have the 3.1 jars installed.  ALso, the package of the app is listed correctly.

Comment: is spring-context among them? can u post the pom.xml?

Comment: Thanks, but I found what went wrong.  It was an incorrect `<mainClass>` attribute.  See my edit.